# I2C and camera issues

Tags: raspbian, i2c, raspicam, mpu6050

Is there any known issue by using I2C components and the RPi Camera at the 
same time?

I am using:

- Raspberry Pi B+, running Raspbian (updated and upgraded to the latest versions)
- MPU6050 3 Axis Gyroscope and Accelerometer
- Raspberry Pi Camera Board

My camera stops working (get stuck, meaning no videos and no error) after a couple hours of usage. There is enough memory and power supply.

Edited:

- Depending on the gyroscope results I record a video with `raspivid`. In the initial two hours it works without any problem, but after that it starts recording but never finishes. If I try to run a new raspivid I get no error message.
- I had a modest overclock but just removed it
- When I2C is not working, the camera does not get stuck
- In `/var/log/syslog` there is:

`INFO: task kworker/0:1:17913 blocked for more than 120 seconds. 
Not tainted 3.18.14+ #792
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message. 
kworker/0:1 D c0551b04 0 17913 2 0x00000000 
Workqueue: events od_dbs_timer
[<c0551b04>] (__schedule) from [<c0551edc>] (schedule+0x40/0x8c)
[<c0551edc>] (schedule) from [<c0554f34>] (schedule_timeout+0x214/0x29c)
[<c0554f34>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0553eec>] (__down+0x90/0xd4) 
[<c0553eec>] (__down) from [<c0056f98>] (down+0xc0/0xc4) 
[<c0056f98>] (down) from [<c001eba4>] (bcm_mailbox_property+0xd0/0x1f0) 
[<c001eba4>] (bcm_mailbox_property) from [<c041d600>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x70/0xcc) [<c041d600>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c0419b5c>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x164/0x2a0) 
[<c0419b5c>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c041b310>] (od_check_cpu+0xac/0xbc)
[<c041b310>] (od_check_cpu) from [<c041cca8>] (dbs_check_cpu+0x104/0x170)
[<c041cca8>] (dbs_check_cpu) from [<c041b680>] (od_dbs_timer+0x70/0xfc)
[<c041b680>] (od_dbs_timer) from [<c003ab2c>] (process_one_work+0x13c/0x444) 
[<c003ab2c>] (process_one_work) from [<c003ba18>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580) 
[<c003ba18>] (worker_thread) from [<c003fe78>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4) 
[<c003fe78>] (kthread) from [<c000e8c8>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)`

Comment: You should explain in better detail what "gets stuck, no video" means.  Does that mean `raspivid` just stops but then can be started again?   If not, what happens when you try to start it again?  Does "no errors" mean you have looked through `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: you'll need to be a bit more specific... how are you reading the video ? are you overclocking ? why do you suspect a problem while using the camera ans I2C at the same time ? does the problem disapear if you don't use your i2c devices ? I'm personally using RPiB+ with servos (i2c  controlled) and a camera. no problem here